# Getting machine name in the svcutil when hosting WCF service

Tags: wcf

I have a domain/website(HTTR.abc.com) hosted in inetmgr in IIS in production servers.
I want to host a WCF service under the domain HTTR.abc.com
The web.config of my WCF service is as follows

```
<services>
<service behaviorConfiguration="HTTR.Business.HTTRContextServiceBehavior" name="HTTR.Business.HTTRContextService">
<endpoint address="http://machinename:83/GTYEBus/abcService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="HTTR.Business.IHTTRContextService">
</endpoint>
</service>
</services>
```

When i run the URL
"http://HTTR.abc.com/GTYEBus/abcService.svc" the page shows properly but it is showing
WSDL file pointing to "http://machinename:83/GTYEBus/abcService.svc?WSDL"

I would want the page to show the WSDL with the same path as the .svc path, that is it should show as "http://HTTR.abc.com/GTYEBus/abcService.svc?WSDL" instead of 
"http://machinename:83/GTYEBus/abcService.svc?WSDL"

Answer (score 1):

I came across this one while tring to find a resolution to the same issue.

This ended up being a issue with the site not having a host name.

In IIS7.5, simply add in the host name into the host header on the binding. If it is https, the host header may be protected. You'll need to make the certificate become a pseudo wildcard cert by putting a * as the start of the certificates friendly name. Then the host name will be editable.

[This link](http://gavinmckay.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/howto-fix-wcf-host-name-on-iis/) has a good description of the resolution in IIS6

Answer (score 0):

In the serviceMetadata section of the web.config you can include the attribute externalMetadataLocation and refer it to the "http://httr.abc.com/GTYEBus/abcService.svc?wsdl" location.  Example:

```
<serviceMetadata externalMetadataLocation="http://httr.abc.com/GTYEBus/abcService.svc?wsdl" />
```

Here is the MSDN reference on the serviceMetaData config section: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731317.aspx.

This does not require any additional IIS configuration and is much more scalable.

Hope this helps.